# Javascript Validation: Page still submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form that is validating one field. The alert box appears on an error and the divs change, but the page continues to submit. I need help figuring out why it is still continuing on.

**Javascript:**

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
    var reason = '';

    reason += validateName(theForm.signature_name);

    if (reason != '') {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "<p>* All fields are required.<br><span style='color:red'><strong><u>Some fields need correction:</u></strong></span></p>" // + reason;    
        //alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function validateName(fld) {
    var error = '';
    var illegalChars = /\W\s/; // allow letters, numbers, and underscores

    if (fld.value == '') {
        error = document.getElementById('client_name').innerHTML = "<h2 id='client_name' style='color:red'>Client's Last Name:</h2><br>The required field has not been filled in.";
        alert("Do Not Continue");
    } else if ((fld.value.length < 2) || (fld.value.length > 15)) {
        error = document.getElementById('client_name').innerHTML = "<h2 id='client_name' style='color:red'>Client's Last Name:</h2><br>The name is not long enough.";
        alert("Do Not Continue");
    } else if (illegalChars.test(fld.value)) {
        error = document.getElementById('client_name').innerHTML = "<h2 id='client_name' style='color:red'>Client's Last Name:</h2><br>The name field contains illegal characters.";
        alert("Do Not Continue");
    }
    return error;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' name='finishJob' id='finishJob' action='finishJob.php' method='POST' onsubmit='return validateFormOnSubmit(this)'>
    <table width='95%' class='tablebox'>
        <tr><td name='error'></td><td><h2>Upload Signature:</h2></br><input name='uploadedfile' id='uploadedfile' type='file' /></td><td><h2 id='client_name'>Client's Last Name:</h2></br><input type='text' id='signature_name' name='signature_name'></td><td><input type='submit' value='Complete Job' class='link-button'></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to return true/false from your validateFormOnSubmit() function, but you're returning a string.

Comment: @LeeTaylor look again...

Comment: The 'reason' is calling the validateName() function, which is returning a value or not based on if there are errors. Then the if statement is checking if the last function sent back anything. If there is something in the 'reason',the if statement should return false, otherwise the statement is returning true. I'm not sure I quite understand what you are saying. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, I saw that oddness after I posted. But, if there are no errors it will return ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ran the code through [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) It shows a random `0` in your code. Also look at your error messages. You copied the same error on every line. You have no opening `<p>` tag.

The reason the form is submitting is probably because of a JS error somewhere in your code. Enable the debugger on your JavaScript console. Go to console and type in

```
validateFormOnSubmit(document.getElementById("finishJob"));
```

Do errors appear in the console?

And when you do that you will see a null error. Why? because you have a name and not an id.

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML <--I am looking for an id
<td name='error'>  <-- I am not an id!
```

Comment: The end p tags must have been from the last time I used this code. I removed them and the 0, still doing the same thing though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: My error console came up with nothing, that's why I put it on here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It came up with nothing because it reset itself, you need to persist the console after the page load.

Answer (score 0):

what if you submit the form in the javascript after validation? like this:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' name='finishJob' id='finishJob' action='finishJob.php' method='POST' onsubmit='javascript:validateFormOnSubmit(this);return false;'>
    <table width='95%' class='tablebox'>
        <tr><td name='error'></td><td><h2>Upload Signature:</h2></br><input name='uploadedfile' id='uploadedfile' type='file' /></td><td><h2 id='client_name'>Client's Last Name:</h2></br><input type='text' id='signature_name' name='signature_name'></td><td><input type='submit' value='Complete Job' class='link-button'></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

function validateFormOnSubmit(theForm) {
var reason = '';

  reason += validateName(theForm.signature_name);

  if (reason != '') {
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="<p>* All fields are required.<br><span style='color:red'><strong><u>Some fields need correction:</u></strong></span></p>"// + reason;   
//alert("Some fields need correction:\n" + reason);
return false;
  } 
  document.finishJob.submit();
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: It's still submitting when it gets to return false;

Comment: Never do it manually, but you should prevent your button to behave normally by calling preventDefault() from your button's events arguments. Test your code against several browsers as the manual way is a high risk-taking. If you can, opt for jQuery validation (well you have then a dependency to jQuery).